# Toggle between divs inside another div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

So I have a div that can have several divs inside of it. Something like:

```
<div id="news">         
    <span>Latest News!</span>       
    <div>
        //News 1    
    </div>
    <div>
        //News 2
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is on page load, the first div is visible, then after so many seconds, it fades out and the second div fades in.  Pretty simple with fadeIn and fadeOut but I have to specifiy each div's actions.  Is there a way to say 'Toggle between every div inside my #news div'? This way I can add new divs without having to add code to hide/show them?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they appearing in the same location? Is one visible behind the other during fade?

Comment: Same location.  Only one visible at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#news div:gt(0)').hide();

    var swap = function(item) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(item).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                var next = $(item).next()[0];
                if (!next) {
                    next = $('#news div')[0];
                }

                $(next).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    swap($(this)[0]);
                })
                    });
        }, 1000);

    };

    swap($('#news div')[0]);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gwzt/2/

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't cycle.  Meaning when it gets to the last div, they all are hidden.

Comment: @drpkcen didn't realize that was the desired behavior.  will update in just a sec

Comment: I think that is it!  Let me add to my site and confirm.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Perfect! One last question, is there an easy way to pause this on mouseover and resume on mouseout?

Comment: @drpcken hmm, not sure. The problem would be canceling the `fadeOut` when a mouse over occurred. I'm actually not sure how that could be done off the top of my head. Perhaps another Q :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// count the number of news items
var len = $("#news div").length;

// hide all but the first
$("#news div:gt(0)").hide();

// set up a counter
var counter = 0;

// function to hide all except the current iteration
function changeDiv() {
    $("#news div").eq(counter).show().siblings("div").hide();
    counter++;

    // when we reach the last one, start again
    if(counter === len) {
        counter = 0;   
    }
}

// go!
var i = setInterval(changeDiv, 2000);
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aTmn9/5/)

Comment: Is there any way to fade these in and out?  I replaced .hide() and .show() with fadeOut() and fadeIn() but it fades back in on the next line like it starts fading in before the previous div fades out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using jQueryUI, which has a tab control: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Otherwise you could give all the divs a common class, say "tab". Then for your tab buttons you can just have:

```
$(".tab").fadeOut();
$("#tab-that-I-want").fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look into using the jQuery Cycle plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need some plugin with content rotation.

Here is one of them: http://demo.smartnetzone.com/auto-rotating-tabs-using-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through the news items. When it reaches the end, it'll start back at the top. Change the 2000 to whatever interval you want (in ms).

```
function switchNewsItem(){
    $('#news div:visible').fadeOut(function(){
        $(this).next().length ? $(this).next().fadeIn() : $('#news div').eq(0).fadeIn();
    });
};
$('#news div').eq(0).show(); // show the first news item
setInterval(switchNewsItem, 2000);
```

See working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ampersand/J6smE/).